# How to find the calling class name of a Thread's start method using stacktrace

Tags: java, swing

can somebody kindly suggest some solution In case I want to get the calling class name of a thread's start method

for example if I start a thread in main the stack trace gives calling class name as thread and caller method name as run for index 2. please help in finding the correct names of the caller class and method name of a thread.

Comment: Whats the problem you are having with getting the callers information using stack trace object ?

Comment: There's no way you can do that, as far as I know. It's not being recorded. You could find out the parent thread, probably, but that will still not mean you'll find out the line of code that called `Thread.start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to tie up tasks that span multiple threads. About the best you can do if you're starting a thread directly is to give it a name in the constructor, then log the calling class and method name along with the new thread's name. But this won't work if you use an `ExecutorService`.

More generally you should investigate using Nested Diagnostic Context to allow you to tie up multi-threaded operations: [Logging activities in multithreaded applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83117/116509)